# 2 wire smoke sensor detection circuit

Tags: sensor, circuit-design, smoke-sensor

I have a System Sensor B401 model smoke sensor.

I want to connect it in 2 wire mode. I want to connect multiple of this smoke sensor in daisy chain fashion with EOL resistor. I read on the internet that it has 2 wires which is a supply as well as detector line.

When there is no smoke, this sensor operates as an open circuit but when there is smoke, then this sensor acts as a short circuit. I wanted to know what is the voltage level on supply line (2 wire) when the smoke is detected (when it gets shorted due to smoke.)

Datasheet link for the sensor is https://www.systemsensor.com/en-us/Documents/B401_Manual_I56-0338.pdf

Also when it becomes short, won't it cause problem to the supply line(2 wire?) What kind of circuit can I use to detect alarm?

Comment: Welcome, probably these would be supplied through a resistor, but you'll need to edit this to provide a link to a data sheet or similar documentation for this component, otherwise the question will probably soon end up closed.

Comment: my guess is that the voltage will be near 0 V when shorted ... put a relay between the power supply and the sensors ... select a relay that gets activated by short-circuit current

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have added link to datasheet

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have connected the device in 2 wire mode as per datasheet. I have not connected remote annunciator as specified. I am not getting any change in voltages even if smoke is detected by sensor.

Comment: (1) "*... even if smoke is detected by sensor.*" How do you know if smoke has been detected? Do you have the LED annunciators fitted? (2) Have you complied with "**Alarm current MUST be limited to 100 mA maximum (130 mA for models 1151 and 2151) by the control panel.*"

Comment: B401 is a base plate for multiple smoke detectors.  The smoke detector you install on the base plate  must be capable of the two wire protocol.  Additionally, the two wire protocol seems to be a bi-directional serial bus.  The control panel can send commands to the detectors as well as receive alarms and other information.  Simply detecting the voltage on the line won't help.

Comment: If your detector is made for two wire operation and you have the supply current limited, then you could probably see pulses on the two wire line when smoke is detected.  You'll need an oscilloscope to see the pulses.

Comment: @Transistor 1. Yes I have LED connected which turns Red when smoke is detected. 2. I even limited the current to 50mA, but there is no change in either current or voltage when smoke is detected?

Comment: @JRE The two wires are meant for 12 volt supply, i guess. How come I send commands over this line. Which protocol can I use for communications. Do you have any link for the protocol for sending commands for this?

Comment: @RaghavendraGaniga, the system seems to use a communications protocol. Your master needs to use this protocol to detect which sensor is actuated. If you don't use a current limited supply then I suspect that you may damage the sensors. You need to read all the documentation.